# Webmail in hosting, redirect website to another IP (VPS)

Tags: dns, cpanel, vps, webmail, vesta

I have a hosting (CPanel) and a VPS (Vesta). The domain is directed by the nameserver to the hosting.

Can I use the CPanel just for the webmail, and the VPS for the website?

I tried to change A name to VPS IP address but the webmail cannot send/receive mail.

Anyone know how to solve my problem?

Comment: Domain NS record is pointed to Cpanel OR Vesta?

Comment: I changed A name to Vesta. But the Cpanel webmail doesnt work after that. @SachinG.

Comment: Domain nameserver are set to cpanel or Vesta, that’s what I mean?

Comment: Oh sorry, nameserver set to Cpanel @SachinG.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know what I wanted to know, will post a workaround in few minutes

Answer (score 0):

In order to use cpanel for webmail the procedure need to follow, there is long process for that but if we do it wisely it takes less than a minute to get it work.

Change domain MX record from existing one to the Cpanel hosting nameserver. For example if your cpanel namerservers are ns1.hostingserver.com & ns2.hostingserver.com then set mx records to ns1.hostingserver.com OR ns2.hostingserver.com

Cpanel should be your primary mode of DNS properties. Set A record for domain to Vesta Server IP address.

This should resolve your issue. Do let me know if you stuck somewhere or need assistance.

Please Note: Every DNS record requires few hrs to propagate so make sure you are giving inf time before testing your technical environment.

Use intodns.com to check records.

Comment: just found that the mx record destination is the domain, is it the key problem?

Comment: Yes, it is. Just change the mx to ns record issue solved :)

Comment: Just to make sure, can I see the ns record using `dig ns domain.com` ?

Comment: Yes you can. Try, check and let me know